# Using a cast and case query help, possible parenthesis issue?

Tags: for-loop, casting, report, case

I'm pretty new to this and I'm hoping it's a simple tweak but I've got a small query that keeps outputting errors in my report.  The original query was:

```
CAST((CASE WHEN (AI.STATUS = 'F' OR AI.STATUS = '*') THEN 'CPL'
           ELSE 'WIP' END) as varchar(10)) as AnalysisStatus,
```

and then I'm trying to modify it to the below.  I've tried different iterations but no luck on anything.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
cast(((CASE
    WHEN AI.STATUS = 'F' THEN 'CPL'
    WHEN (AI.STATUS = '*' AND AI.METHOD.FULL <> 'METHOD') THEN 'CPL'
    ELSE 'WIP' END)) as varchar(10)) as AnalysisStatus,
```

Comment: You open four parentheses and close five; fix that.

Comment: I'm not seeing it.  I have 5 open and 5 closing, i'm not saying they're not in the wrong places or needed but there is an equal amount of each.

Comment: That's how I count it now -- sorry for the drive-by!